# import django models classes into utility module

Tags: django, django-models

I have two model classes in my models.py module in the default location.

```
PythonFinal
    |_   manage.py
    |_  template
    |_ PythonFinal
    |       |_  __init__.py
    |       |_  settings.py
    |       |_  urls.py
    |       |_  swgi.py
    | 
    |      
    |___ fertility
            |_  __init__.py
            |_  models.py
            |_  tests.py
            |_  views.py
            |_  dateUtils.py
```

I simply want to import the classes into dateUtils.py

```
from fertility.models import Cycle, Period

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = Period(periodFirstDay='2012-7-26' , periodNumber=4)
```

If I run this module I get

```
ImportError: no module named fertility
```

If I try to import models from the python commandline I get

```
import models    
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "models.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.db import models
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
        if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
        self._setup()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
        raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
    ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I added my projects root folder to the PYTHONPATH in ~/.bashrc.
My wsgi.py reads

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "PythonFinal.settings")
```

I do not think it is not a circular import because I get the ImportError instead of a NamingError, and I simply don't have many imports yet. For obvious reasons I need to be able to import my model to other modules I can unit test or I need another simple workflow that accomplishes the same.

Comment: To use models from the commandline, you should **always** start the shell using `./manage.py shell` rather than going into Python directly. That will avoid the issues with DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

Comment: that yielded...                                                      >>> import fertility.dateUtils.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jeremy/PythonFinal/fertility/dateUtils.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PythonFinal.fertility.models import Cycle, Period
ImportError: No module named fertility.models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `PythonFinal` is in `/home/users/jeremy/django/PythonFinal`, then `/home/users/jeremy/django` should be in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, and `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` should be set to `"PythonFinal.PythonFinal.settings"`. Then you can use

```
from PythonFinal.fertility.models import Cycle, Period
```

from the Python command line.

It is, however, more common to have the `settings.py` file in the same folder as `manage.py`, and a number of tools and tutorials expect this setup...

Comment: I added those values to ~/.bashrc and sourced it, now I just get ImportError: No module named MySiteDir.fertility.models

Comment: Can you update your question with the real directory structure?

Comment: Is it more common to have settings.py and manage.py in the same folder in older versions of Django? I used 1.4 and followed the Djangoproject.com First steps tutorial and I set up the directories per the instructions.